# My app freezes crashes when it's supposed to go to the next activity

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception

I don't know why the app crashes whenever it's supposed to go to the next `Activity`. I made a practice app that works as it should when using the same format. I uploaded the files to [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/asonofman).

**The error is**

```
1216-1216/com.example.chiozokamalu.newfreshstart E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            at com.example.chiozokamalu.newfreshstart.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:164)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

On line 164 of MainActivity.java:

```
questionView.setText(questions[questionIndex]); // set the text to the next question
```

EDIT: After Varun helped me, I get a new error which is

```
1307-1307/com.example.chiozokamalu.newfreshstart E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chiozokamalu.newfreshstart/com.example.chiozokamalu.newfreshstart.Results1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.chiozokamalu.newfreshstart.Results1.onCreate(Results1.java:58)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show us any Crash log from andorid logcat.

Comment: It says java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
            at com.example.chiozokamalu.newfreshstart.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:164), so what's on line 164 in MainActivity.java?

Comment: @Pang                                         questionView.setText(questions[questionIndex]); // set the text to the next question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions array at line no. 164 is going out of bound that means questionIndex is greater than the total length of the questions array. So you should add a check on the length before extracting value from the array.

You have added the check but after that you incremented the value so either you modify the if condition to `if (questionIndex < questions.length -1)`

or modify the questionIndex variable before the if condition

You are getting problem because you haven't initiated resultView9 that is why it is null and giving nullpointer, just initiatlise it as you done with other and everything is fine. You have initialised the resultView8 twice just add resultview9 over there

Comment: What do you mean by "Add a check"? and I did change to "if (questionIndex < questions.length -1)" but still I get errors

Comment: ok do one thing the put the questionIndex++ line before the if (questionIndex < questions.length ) check and see what happens

Comment: still doesn;t work Since I can't post everything, becuase of limited text space. heres the errors that show up at the first lines "1307-1307/com.example.chiozokamalu.newfreshstart E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chiozokamalu.newfreshstart/com.example.chiozokamalu.newfreshstart.Results1}: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: The exception is different now it has been changed to nullpointer from Index out of bound and now the error is in your 2nd activity that means the second activity is launching. Please edit your question and add the full logcat there. The problem is almost resolved

Comment: Got the problem you haven't initiated resultView9 that is why it is null and giving nullpointer, just initiatlise it as you done with other and everything is fine. You have initialised the resultView8 twice just add resultview9 over there